# html_safe, raw, h have all failed to render links in text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I happen to be passing a url within the message body in my model_class. The link renders out well in views but it is unclickable (as a user has to manually copy it). Below is how i am passing the link in model class.

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
    messsage_body = "Hi! Follow this link to say hi! #{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_say_hi_url(@user, :host => "localhost:3000")
end
```

Try calling it in my view with following:

```
<%= @something.message_body.html_safe %>
<%= raw @something.message_body %>
<%= h @something.message_body %>
```

And the link still remains un-clickable.

Hope mt explanation was clear enough thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The link is unclickable because you are not actually making it a link using rails' `link_to` helpers or creating a HTML anchor tag manually or any other method. You are just printing out a URL.